# Opening docked on screen keyboard

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-8, tablet

I've been working with Windows 8 tablets this week, and I need to display an on screen keyboard in my program.  Right now I'm using

```
Shell("cmd.exe /c start osk")
```

which gives me the standard windows 8 on screen keyboard

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iFhr.png

But what I'd like to do is open up the docked, wider keyboard like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzfNj.png

I'm not sure if this is a windows 8 function or a tablet specific keyboard.  I'm using an ASUS transformer right now, but this program needs to run on a variety of windows 8 tablets.

the desired end result is a larger keyboard, preferably docked at the bottom of the screen.

Anyone know of a solution?

(sorry about the links, I dont have the rep yet to post images.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've developed a working answer for this.  It's not ideal but so far it works

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\TabTip.exe") Then
        Process.Start("C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\TabTip.exe")
        'ElseIf My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\TabTip32.exe") Then
        '    Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\TabTip32.exe")
    Else
        Shell("cmd.exe /c start osk")
    End If
```

tabtip.exe was what I was looking for.  There's also a tabtip32.exe in the \programfiles (x86)\ directory, but that's not working for me.